# Form added field but Actual execution not appear

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I would like to add a column Journal number on the settlement Form (form VendOpenTrans), however the actual form from journal is not showing the newly added Column

[image: Column added as display in design tab]

[image: Propeties that is used on Journal Number]

[image: Column Journal Number is not shown]

I have attempt to duplicate those field that are visible, rename and re-path to Journal Number, but the Field is Not shown as well.  Did I miss out any steps to show out the Fields?

Below is my XPO
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QOLvXqMyEL722ja0ySfOAsRIJEj5nkmZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the properties of the control that is used to show the journal number.

Comment: Have you added the VendTrans.JournalNum field in the relevant grid?

https://i.imgur.com/3MzLQAX.png

Comment: Yes I have added JournalNum in the grid, otherwise at design tab which is shown in the first figure will not show up

Comment: @Raynon, what does the AOT design look like?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue, but for me it works. Do you have other customizations on that form, probably something that controls visibility of controls or data source fields? Maybe you can share the .xpo of your customization.

Comment: @FH-Inway That one I am not sure, the XPO is shared as above edited comment

Comment: @Raynon I imported the .xpo and the column Journal Number is shown in the form. Maybe try to do the same on another system that does not have the customization yet. You could also try compiling and restoring the form. Other than that I'm not sure how we can help you without taking a look at your system.

Comment: One thing I have notice that all newly added field, regardless create by it own or duplicate from previous field will not be shown

Comment: @Raynon, have you flushed your temp data?

Comment: @mrsalonen could you elaborate what does it means by flush temp data?

Comment: @Raynon, check this out https://ashdynamicsax.wordpress.com/2018/12/10/post24-clearing-usage-data-cache/

Comment: @Raynon Have you tried resetting your usage data and/or restarting the AOS?

Comment: @mrsalonen that was a good advice, but it is not working for me.

Comment: @AlexKwitny I have resetting usage data, not working. btw how to restart AOS?

Comment: @Raynon AOS is a Windows service. You restart it like any other service.